# Convert Python date to Unix timestamp

Tags: python-2.7, unix, datetime

I would like to convert a Python `date` object to a Unix timestamp.

I already added a `time` object, so it would be that specific date at midnight, but I don't know how to continue from there.

```
d = date(2014, 10, 27)
t = time(0, 0, 0)
dt = datetime.combine(d, t)

#How to convert this to Unix timestamp?
```

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the unix time like this:

```
import time
from datetime import date

d = date(2014, 10, 27)

unixtime = time.mktime(d.timetuple())
```

Comment: `mktime()` accepts the time in the local timezone. [It may fail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).

Comment: unixtime = int(time.mktime(d.timetuple())) ... no decimal.

Answer (score 5):

Unix time can be derived from a `datetime` object like this:

```
d = date(2014, 10, 27)
t = time(0, 0, 0)
dt = datetime.combine(d, t) 

unix = dt.strftime('%s')
# returns 1414364400, which is 2014-10-27 00:00:00
```

Comment: `'%s'` is not supported by Python. It is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
timestamp = date_converter.date_to_timestamp(d)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date(2014, 10, 27)
>>> int("{:%s}".format(d))
1414364400
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1414364400)
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 27, 0, 0)
```

Please note that `%s` formatting of times is not supported on Windows.