# Converting to unix timestamp Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am trying to convert a datestamp of now into Unix TimeStamp, however the code below seems to be hit but then just jumps to the end of my app, as in seems to not like the time.mktime part.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

now = datetime.now()
toDayDate = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
newDate = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(toDayDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
print(newDate)
```

Comment: add a `*`: `time.mktime(*date...`

Comment: `strptime` parses a date string based on the format spec -- `toDayDate` is not a date string, it's a date so you shouldn't need to be parsing anything there ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python date to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298677/convert-python-date-to-unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change

`newDate = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(toDayDate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())`

to

`newDate = time.mktime(datetime.timetuple())`

as an example I did:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
t = datetime.now()
unix_secs = mktime(t.timetuple())
```

and got  `unix_secs = 1488214742.0`

Credit to @tarashypka- use `t.utctimetuple()` if you want the result in UTC (e.g. if your datetime object is aware of timezones)

Comment: for timezone aware datetime objects use `utctimetuple()` instead of `timetuple()`

Answer (score 12):

You could use `datetime.timestamp()` in Python 3 to get the POSIX timestamp instead of using `now()`.

The value returned is of type float. `timestamp()` relies on [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) which in turn relies on `mktime()`. However, `datetime.timestamp()` supports more platforms and has a wider range of values.