# attribute error while trying to convert datetime to unix timestamp in python 2.7

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, attributeerror

I'm querying a database to get a datetime and then trying to convert it to a unix timestamp. Here is some of my code:

```
#! /bin/python
import time, pytz
from datetime import datetime

eastern = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")

def toUnix(dt):
    #converts a datetime to a unix timestamp
    return time.mktime(dt.timetuple())

def getFillStartTime(fillNo):
    #returns the start time of a fill as a unix time stamp
    dsacursor.execute('select startTime from fillInfo where fillNo = @fillNo',{'@fillNo':fillNo})
    sel = dsacursor.fetchall()
    dt = sel[0][0]
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo = eastern)
    return toUnix(dt)

print getFillStartTime(20318)
```

When I run it I'm getting `AttributeError: replace` here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print getFillStartTime(20318)
  File "importToLogView.py", line 25, in getFillStartTime
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo = eastern)
AttributeError: replace
```

I have tested some things and `dt` of type `DateTimeType` when it is passed to the `toUnix()` function. Also, when I replace `dt.timetuple()` with `datetime.now().timetuple()` it prints the expected result. I have also tried not replacing the tzinfo and it gives `AttributeError: timetuple` instead. If it is a datetime, why is this error occurring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting to unix timestamp Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491129/converting-to-unix-timestamp-python)

Comment: What is the output if you put `print type(dt)` after `dt = sel[0][0]`?

Comment: `<type 'DateTimeType'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming that `sel` will be a datetime object, but it's not. It's not possible to derive that from the code snippet you have posted, and most likely is being returned as a string (database client depending). The general form for doing so is

`dt = datetime.strptime(sel[0][0], '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')`

where `%b %d %Y %I:%M%p` is the format of the string.

EDIT: formatting

Comment: if I `print type(dt)` after `dt = sel[0][0]` the output is `<type 'DateTimeType'>`

Comment: Yes, I would assume so, because your database client is most likely casting that. Python datetime (and pytz) doesn't understand that, so you'll need to get it into `<type 'datetime.datetime'>` or something similar. Also, what database client are you using?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I'm using Sybase.