# When I use apply function in pandas, it shows "TypeError: must be string, not float"

Tags: python, pandas

One column in dataframe is like this:

```
2018-01-23 23:55:07
```

I want to convert the values in this column to unix time.
Below is my code:

```
 def convert_to_unix(s):
    return float(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple()))
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
fields=['JOB_START_TIMESTAMP','JOB_END_TIMESTAMP','JOB_RUNTIME_SECONDS', 'JOB_NODES_USED']
df_temp=pd.read_csv('a.csv',usecols=fields)
df_temp['JOB_START_TIMESTAMP']=df_temp['JOB_START_TIMESTAMP'].apply(convert_to_unix)
```

Then it shows error`TypeError: must be string, not float`.
[error_ image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbTG7.png)
Can anybody help me? Thanks very much!

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491129/converting-to-unix-timestamp-python)

Comment: Are you sure your error isn't `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float`?

Comment: if your column `JOB_START_TIMESTAMP` actually contains time stamp with quotes, you need to change your format string from `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`  to `"'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"`.

Comment: @Kumar: I wouldn't expect a quoting issue to generate the mentioned TypeError.

Comment: The time stamp does not contain quotes and the error is what I wrote. I attach a picture about error, you can click the error_image to see it. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski my bad. I hadn't paid attention to the error message. @tjuli However, if you just need your job done, can you try this code `df_temp['JOB_START_TIMESTAMP'] = df_temp['JOB_START_TIMESTAMP'].apply(pd.Timestamp).apply(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)`

Comment: still not works, if I use a for loop to read each row and change the value one by one, it works. But I can not find a more concise way.

Comment: @tjuli can you try storing this timestamp value to a new column? e.g. `df_temp["JOB_START_TIMESTAMP_FLOAT"] = df_temp["JOB_START_TIMESTAMP"].apply(pd.Timestamp).apply(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)` also make sure that your column data type is indeed &quot;object&quot; by `df_temp.info()`

Answer (score 0):

Code below converts a date column (`datetime64[ns]`) to unix time (`float64`).

**Import libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
```

**Create sample dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-01-23 23:55:07', '2017-01-23 23:55:07', '2015-11-23 11:50:07',
'2013-01-03 13:55:07', '2007-01-24 23:55:07', '2017-12-23 12:55:07']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df
```

[image]

**Function that converts to unix time**

```
 def convert_to_unix(s):
    return df.apply(lambda x: mktime((x['Date']).timetuple()),axis=1)
```

**Get unix time**

```
df['unix_time'] = convert_to_unix(df)
df
```

[image]

```
df.dtypes
```

[image]

**Alternative without using function**

```
df['unix_time'] = df.apply(lambda x: mktime((x['Date']).timetuple()),axis=1)
df
```

Comment: I paster your code without modification. But it pops error: Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1

Comment: I have updated the call to function. It should work now. Also added a line at the end of the code, that should work without calling the 'convert_to_unix()' function

Comment: @tjuli just thought should check with you if the code was working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kunar. My problem is there is NaTType in my data.
His answer works and is concise since it is in the comments and hided, I just put it here.
df_temp['JOB_START_TIMESTAMP']=df_temp['JOB_START_TIMESTAMP'].apply(pd.Timestamp).apply(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)