# How to convert time column to Unix timestamp?

Tags: python, json, stockquotes

[image]

I would like to convert Datetime column to Epoch / Unix timestamp.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import time
df = yf.download(tickers='^NSEI',period='1d',interval='15m')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {'Datetime':'time'}, inplace = True)
df['Date'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
df
```

Comment: remove the image and share text only.

Comment: @balderman i have updated code and image is for Columns reference

Comment: What is the problem? What did you try and how it failed? Where are the `import` statements ?  How can we reproduce your code without it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting to unix timestamp Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491129/converting-to-unix-timestamp-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this provide function [citation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58187886/6651840)

```py
def utctimestamp(ts: str, DATETIME_FORMAT: str = "%d/%m/%Y"):
    import datetime, calendar
    ts = datetime.datetime.utcnow() if ts is None else datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, DATETIME_FORMAT)
    return calendar.timegm(ts.utctimetuple())
```

Example code (not tested)

```py
# Imports
import datetime, calendar

# custom function
def utctimestamp(ts: str, DATETIME_FORMAT: str = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"):
    ts = datetime.datetime.utcnow() if ts is None else datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, DATETIME_FORMAT)
    return calendar.timegm(ts.utctimetuple())

# updated code
df = yf.download(tickers='^NSEI',period='1d',interval='15m')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns = {'Datetime':'time'}, inplace = True)
df['Date'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['time'] = utctimestamp(df['time'].dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: it works when i enter single row value but not apply for all see image 1 https://ibb.co/myPb0ks  and image 2 https://ibb.co/2ckFxNC as you can see when i am calling series its not working any fix for it?